How to join all of the polygons that intersects and leave others without change in R - sf?
I am trying to do exactly what is described in this question: How to join all of the polygons that intersects and leave others without change in postgis? but with R and more specifically with the sf and tidyverse packages.
It seems the ST_ClusterIntersecting function is not implemented in the sf package.

Could you expand on the question here and show maybe some sample data and output - linked questions might get removed at some point and that breaks this one. Its okay to link to other questions, but not when the current question depends so strongly on the linked one.

st_union does this, but do you have the computational problems mentioned in the linked-to question? Do you have attributes for the polygons and how do you deal with them for overlapping polygons? Or are they guaranteed equal for overlapping polygons?

Here is a slightly complicated way to do this using sf in R along with tidyverse.
First, some example data:
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(tmap)

poly1 = data.frame(lat = c(43.5,43.5,42.5,42.5),
                   lon = c(-78.5,-77.5,-77.5,-78.5)) %>%
  st_as_sf(.,coords = c('lon','lat')) %>%
  summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry)) %>%
  st_convex_hull()

poly2 = data.frame(lat = c(45.5,45.5,44.5,44.5),
                   lon = c(-78.5,-77.5,-77.5,-78.5)) %>%
  st_as_sf(.,coords = c('lon','lat')) %>%
  summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry)) %>%
  st_convex_hull()

poly3 = data.frame(lat = c(44,44,43,43),
                   lon = c(-79,-78,-79,-78)) %>%
  st_as_sf(.,coords = c('lon','lat')) %>%
  summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry)) %>%
  st_convex_hull()

union = rbind(poly1,poly2,poly3)
union$id = 1:nrow(union)

tm_shape(poly1,bbox=st_bbox(union))+tm_borders(col='red')+
  tm_shape(poly2)+tm_borders(col='green')+
  tm_shape(poly3)+tm_borders(col='blue')


Notice we have three unique polygons stored within one object called union. If we intersect this to each other like so:
intersector = st_intersects(union)

we are returned a list containing the combinations of polygons that are intersecting. From here, we can create a simple loop that returns all polygons that should be joined together and those that should be left alone based on a grouping variable:
for(i in 1:nrow(intersector)){
  if(i == 1){to_combine = union[unlist(intersector[[i]]),]
  to_combine$pair = i}
  if(i > 1){to_combine2 = union[unlist(intersector[[i]]),]
  to_combine2$pair = i
  to_combine = rbind(to_combine,to_combine2)}
}

Note, the object returned will contain duplicates, but these will be removed in the next step. The next step groups the polygons, removes our grouping column, and then identifies duplicated geometries which are then removed:
unionized = to_combine %>%
  group_by(pair) %>%
  summarize() %>%
  select(-pair) %>%
  distinct()

The result:
tm_shape(unionized[1,],
         bbox = st_bbox(unionized))+
  tm_borders(col = 'purple')+
tm_shape(unionized[2,])+
  tm_borders(col='green')


